# Android failed sms observer

Tags: java, android, sms, contentobserver

I'm trying to write an Android service app which intercepts failed outgoing sms messages (due to service unavailable) to store them and try to resend them as soon as the phone service is back. I almost got it to work, but i have this problem, which is not so simple to explain but i'll try, hoping you understand: 
I have set a ContentObserver on the URI content://sms even if what i'm interested on is content://sms/failure because if i set it on this last URI the onChange method doesn't get triggered, and i don't know why. Provided successfully sent and received messages don't bother me since, in the onChange method in the observer, I read just the content in content://sms/failed, here is the real problem: onChange gets triggered also on DELETE events, of course, which occur, for example, in the moment a previously failed message is succesfully sent. This is bad for my application because if I can't distinguish between a delete event and an add event i don't know if i have to add or not the first sms in the failed message queue into the "resend" list. So, my question is: is there a way to distinguish between delete an add events with a content observer?

PS: It would be nice to understand why a ContentObserver on content://sms/failed doesn't work.

PPS: I have another minor issue: i'm resending the messages using the SmsManager, which works fine, the only problem is i can only set the destination number and the body of the message but not the ID of the message, so when i resent an sms the system think it's just a new sms and not an old one being resent (and so the old failed messages remains in the queue and doesn't get removed by the system).

Comment: Goodness!.. MY EYES!!! TL;DR Please make more readable.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there a way to distinguish between delete an add events with a content observer?

Query the URI passed into the `onChange()` method. If the Cursor is empty - i.e., `getCount()` returns `0` - then it was a deletion. For example:

```
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)
{
    boolean deletion = false;

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,
                                               null, null);

    if(cursor != null)
        deletion = cursor.getCount() == 0;
    else
        return;

    ...
}
```

> It would be nice to understand why a ContentObserver on content://sms/failed doesn't work.

That's just how the SMS ContentProvider is implemented. You can't get any more specific than `content://sms`.

> I have another minor issue...

The ID for a message is assigned by the ContentProvider, and the soonest your app can know its value is in the `onChange()` method. You have no control over the assignment of IDs, so your app will have to track failed message IDs itself, and delete the appropriate message upon a successful send.

Comment: For the first answer: it's incorrect if there is more than 1 message in the query result. Whenever a failed message is intercepted i read just the first result Of the query, since for every new failed message event a new call to onChange is generated, so no need to read more than one entry. 

OK for the second answer.

For the last one, I already know I can obtain the SMS id in the onChange method and I do infact. I don't know how to delete the SMS from the content://sms/failed though.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be getting more than one message in your query's result. 2) That's what your app is going to have to track - the IDs/URIs of the failed sends. After a successful send, `delete()` the saved URI.

Comment: I realize now that I might not have been too clear in the first part of my answer. I think you might be using the wrong query, so I've added an example. I can't be much more specific about the last part of my answer without knowing a little more about how your app is meant to function.

Comment: I used the exact same query as you did. The problem is I already check cur.getCount() == 0 and it ISN'T true when a deletion occurs. Doing debug, I can just see that cur.getCount() is equal to the cardinality of the content://SMS/failed. So, for example, if there are failed messages in the system (in the android system I mean) BEFORE I install my application, cur.getCount() will always count also those messages. Now I'm not on my pc, as soon as I get to it I'll post some code if it's still needed.

Comment: Yes, all of them have an assigned _id. But my problem is NOT how to do the deletion of the resended messages through the _id, the real problem is that when a deletion occurs (i mean WHATEVER deletion for example one the user manually do in the sms app), the onChange method is triggered with no possibility to understand if that call was a deletion or a new failed sms outgoing.
Here is the code of my onChange anyway:

Comment: Yes, all of them have an assigned _id. But my problem is NOT how to do the deletion of the resended messages through the _id, the real problem is that when a deletion occurs (i mean WHATEVER deletion, for example one the user manually do in the sms app), the onChange method is triggered with no possibility to understand if that call was a deletion or a new failed sms outgoing.

Comment: So it happens that, for example,if in the failed sms database (let's se it as a stack) there is an old failed sms generated before my application was installed, and another failed message on top of it, generated while my app was running, in the moment i delete the message on top, onChange gets triggered, reads the database and find the old message and inserts it in the smsToResend list.

Comment: Here is the code of my onChange anyway:
http://pastebin.com/rgwAYh7G  (sorry, i don't know how to make a code box)
The variable lastSms contains the last read failed sms from the database, so that if onChange is triggered by an sms received or a successfully sent sms it doesn't reinsert the sms into the smsToSend list. writeToDatabase is just a method to write that list into a file.

Comment: Look at your `onChange()` method again. Yours is not like my example. There are two `onChange()` methods. You want the one that passes in a URI, like in my example. That is the URI you should be querying, not your `uriSMSURI`. That URI should be for a single message.

Comment: Ok, now I understood how the onChange works. Thank you. Almost everything works now, but i have 2 weird problems in this chunk of code: http://pastebin.com/d8XBQG0v

Basically, getColumnIndex return an index -1 in the first problem, which is really weird since my getCount() isn't 0 and the "type" column is in the selection list.

The second problem is that the delete method return 0 (no row deleted), which is also really weird since the sms with the specified id DOES exist since i got it in the first query (getCount() != 0)

Comment: 1) You need to move the Cursor to a row before you try to retrieve a value. Add `cur.moveToFirst()` before the line you have marked. 2) It should be `Uri.parse("content://sms/" + sms.getId())`.

Comment: Ok, the moveToFirst() (or moveToNext()) missing was a stupid mistake... but i still have problems with the deletion. I was already using Uri.parse("content://sms/" + sms.getId())  (i edited my previous comment, i don't know if you read the old version). This is my code now, with the deletion not working: http://pastebin.com/39iR3h78